# Issue with resolving package dependencies in Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

Issue with resolving package dependencies in Composer

I'm encountering a problem with Composer when trying to resolve package dependencies.

I have two modules, alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module and alexisvs/multipass-testing-module, where the second module is required by the first one.

I want to manage these modules separately, so I've moved the alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module requirement from the main composer.json file to a separate composer.modules.json file.

Here are the relevant details:

```
Main composer.json file:
```

```json
{
    ...
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper"
            ]
        },
        "merge-plugin": {
            "include": [
                "composer.modules.json"
            ],
            "require": [
                "composer.modules.json"
            ],
            "recurse": true,
            "replace": false,
            "ignore-duplicates": false,
            "merge-dev": true,
            "merge-extra": true,
            "merge-extra-deep": false,
            "merge-replace": true,
            "merge-scripts": false
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true
        },
        "github-oauth": {
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

```
composer.modules.json:
```

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "packages/alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module": "^0.0.1"
    }
}
```

```
alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module composer.json:
```

```json
{
    "name": "alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/AlexisVS/multipass-testing-module"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        ...
        "alexisvs/multipass-testing-module": "dev-main"
    },
    ...
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "phpstan/extension-installer": true
        },
        "github-oauth": {
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

```
alexisvs/multipass-testing-module composer.json:
```

```json
{
    "name": "alexisvs/multipass-testing-module",
    "version": "1.0.3",
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
    },
   
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

However, when running composer update -vvv, I get the following error message:

```
Updating dependencies
Generating rules
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.
Something's changed, looking at all rules again (pass #1)
Dependency resolution completed in 0.009 seconds
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/alexisvs/multipass-testing-module~dev.json
[404] https://repo.packagist.org/p2/alexisvs/multipass-testing-module~dev.json
Downloading https://packagist.org/providers/alexisvs/multipass-testing-module.json
[200] https://packagist.org/providers/alexisvs/multipass-testing-module.json
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module ^0.0.1 -> satisfiable by alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module[0.0.1].
    - alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module 0.0.1 requires alexisvs/multipass-testing-module dev-main -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I have referenced the module repository url so why it tries to reach my module at https://packagist.org/providers/alexisvs/multipass-testing-module.json ?

Comment: in `composer.modules.json` try `"require": { "alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module": "@dev" }`

Comment: the `alexisvs/multipass-second-testing-module` is correctly loaded this is the second one which doesn't want to be loaded

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your question, very interesting. You asked:

> I have referenced the module repository url [sic!] so why it tries to reach my module at https://packagist.org/providers/alexisvs/multipass-testing-module.json?

Indeed, by the sheer look at the URL, an authors view must immediately spot ones own package name in the URL, here yours `alexisvs/multipass-testing-module`. And then draw the conclusion this "tries to reach my module".

But it does not.

Requests to Packagist basing in `/providers/` path are not reaching for the module name itself, but this is the API endpoint to discover *other* packages that use the [`provide` property](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#provide) in their config.

> For example https://packagist.org/providers/monolog/monolog.json lists some package which have a "provide" rule for monolog/monolog, but it does not list monolog/monolog itself. *([ref](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#providers-api))*

TLDR: It does not try to reach your package `alexisvs/multipass-testing-module`.